# Indexing an Angular.js website with html5mode

Tags: seo, html5, angular.js

I'm currently developing a website with AngularJS 1 and I have a big problem with SEO.

I have decided to use html5mode to beautify the URLs, but Google, despite the research about this subject, doesn't get the javascript content (example: title of the homepage which is between `{{ }})`.

Pre-rendering HTML pages is deprecated so I don't know what to do.

Comment: The best thing to try is [check your website on google fetch and render tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch), if Googlebot render your sites correctly then it will index correctly as well.

Comment: Thank you, but the rendering only works for the homepage, but on others, I got a redirect message (it's to avoid 404 errors when a user try to access  a page with the URL directly)

Comment: Instead of redirecting you should serve the same application at other URLs then let the JavaScript show the correct content.

Comment: I don't understand, if I don't redirect, I get no content (404 error), the server doesn't recognized the route so JavaScript can't do someting

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX scheme was officially deprecated as of October 2015. Google now recommends that you use server-side rendering with the Angular framework using Angular Universal --> https://universal.angular.io/.

You should be serving SEO friendly URLs from your application to both users and bots. As this will help Google understand what the content on the page is about.

Some tips on JS and modern websites from Google's John Mueller if you want to hear it from a Google employee --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlP5rBynK3E.